# Is it possible to control android volume with mouse scroll in OTG connection?

Tags: android

I want to control specifically the Youtube app volume with the OTG mouse wheel.
I tried through using a web view and controlling the mouse events but the native player was staying alive and making a mess.
Then I tried with the Youtube app and looking for a way to map the key events but I havent found anything. If theres any way to do it, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have something similar.
I solved my problem using a service and putting a view at the top of the screen, like Facebook conversations globes, so I can implement events listeners on that view. And that way I was able to increase/decrease volume in android with a mouse scroll wheel in any application but with some limitations, you have to hover at the top of the screen.

Hope this helps.